# How to set system wide proxy in ICS

Tags: android, networking, properties, proxy, wifi

For Android 3.x and before, you can bring up a hidden UI called com.android.settings.ProxySelector. It is set in Settings.Secure.HTTP_PROXY and used by Mobile network (WiFi network does not always work). However for ICS, I can still bring up this hidden UI, but it does not seem to set proxy anymore. When I click "Done", then I check Settings.Secure.HTTP_PROXY or system property http.proxyHost, neither is set.

So is there a way in ICS that would allow me to set global proxy much like what I can do before with the com.android.settings.ProxySelector UI? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately the hidden activity "com.android.settings.ProxySelector" is not designed for setting the proxy for Wi-Fi networks. In fact you can set a global proxy using this activity but for standard applications you won't see a change.

For example the default browser use this setting only for **MOBILE** networks and completely ignore it for **Wi-Fi** networks.

Of course you can read the settings in your personal app using this [library](https://github.com/shouldit/android-proxy-library), but you can't expect that other applications will do the same :(

Please let me know if everything is clear. Anyway I'm trying to cover the problem [here](http://www.android-proxy.com/), so you can find more resources on this topic.

Comment: Thanks, @LeChunk! What I noticed is that com.android.settings.ProxySelector does not work for mobile network either for ICS devices. Even after I set proxy in the UI, if I do Settings.Secure.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.HTTP_PROXY), I will not get anything, meaning it was not really set. Did you see the same problem? I also do System.getProperty("http.proxyHost"), but also nothing.

Comment: Just modified my original post to be more clear that I am more concerned about mobile data side than Wifi side.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have an ICS device with an official ROM installed. But I tried on an unofficial ICS ROM seems that the method: `Settings.Secure.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.HTTP_PROXY)` always return null. Don't know why. This is another clue that confirm that we shouldn't use the `com.android.settings.ProxySelector` activity on newer versions.

Comment: Yes, that's what I see on my device as well. I also tried ICS emulator and same behavior. So this activity has no effect now? Then how can I set proxy for mobile network then? Some carriers don't have APN that the user can edit.

Comment: I think that you just need to edit the APN settings into your device.

Comment: But some carriers don't allow customers change APN directly. I did some more research and it seems that Android deprecated Settings.Secure.HTTP_PROXY in ICS with global_http_proxy_host but I could not find anything about it. Just posted another question on this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611381/settings-secure-http-proxy-deprecated-in-ics-but-no-information-on-replacement

Comment: Check out this answer for some more details on Android's Proxy situation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10811698/getting-wifi-proxy-settings-in-android/13616054#13616054

Answer (score 1):

if the device is rooted. you can edit the Iptable

Comment: Thankd Changwei. But I am looking for solutions for non-rooted devices.

Comment: This is not for my own phone. My phone is always rooted. :-)