# Android:create a proxy server

Tags: android

How can i create a proxy server to monitor my users in my android..

I tried to create proxy server using this code ..But that not getting created..Did i do anything wrong in that please state..

```
public void setProxy(DefaultHttpClient httpclient) {  
    final String PROXY_IP = "127.0.0.1";  
     final int PROXY_PORT = 8080;  

     httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(  
             new AuthScope(PROXY_IP, PROXY_PORT),  
             new UsernamePasswordCredentials(  
                     "root", "password"));  

    HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(PROXY_IP, PROXY_PORT);  

    httpclient.getParams().setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY,  
            proxy);  

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this way you are configuring proxy for your application's HttpClient.
Recent versions of Android do not support system-wide proxy at all. Check this for some more details: [How to set system wide proxy in ICS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10559370/how-to-set-system-wide-proxy-in-ics)

Comment: Thanx for your response..If is it possible when i root my device..?

Comment: @Coder, theoretically yes - you would have all the opportunities to bring this functionality back by modifying system libraries (HttpClient) and/or implementing transparent proxy redirect via `iptables`. But it is a whole bunch of work to do, not just couple lines of code.

Comment: @ Andrey Voitenkov:Aww..I breaking my head to do this for last couple of days..And now i turning to rooted devices to acheive my task..Could you help me to do this by giving some reference materials or sample codes..!

Comment: I alreay did. There are links in the accepted answer of the question I pointed in this answer :)
Check APL (Android Proxy Library) first of all.

Comment: If i created manually the proxy server in my mobile means ..Then will it be possible to get the users response..?