# Using an Android APP with WIFI Proxy connection

Tags: android, proxy, client-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How Android application decide if they want to use network proxy or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544582/how-android-application-decide-if-they-want-to-use-network-proxy-or-not)

I have a client server application where the client sends a file from the android phone to the server which is on amazon ec2.

I was wondering if i can use this application and establish a connection between the client and server even if the WIFI the client is connected to has a proxy (from which i have a username and password).

if not, what should i do to make it work?

btw it seems there is this app [proxydroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.proxydroid&hl=en). My android version is 2.3, it seems they solved it for 3.2 and above  as shown [here](http://acer--uk.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/12638/~/setting-proxy-settings-in-android-3.2). Any other recommendations?

Comment: have a look on this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544582/how-android-application-decide-if-they-want-to-use-network-proxy-or-not http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431345/set-wifi-proxy-without-rooting-phone

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the proxy is to identify users using mac address and allowing the users through authentication process, So you can't expect anonymous connection. Otherwise we should depend or write application for android